# Custom Taxonomy in default RSS feed

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have been using the code here - https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/ - to create a custom taxonomy. But now I want that custom taxonomy info to be included in the site's default RSS feed. I dont want to create a new feed for the custom taxonomy, but merely include the custom taxonomy info in the default feed.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.